# Swift - Programatically resize TableView height based on content

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I am new to Swift/Xcode and need help on the following: I have two TableViews in an UIViewController to show regional census data.  The top TableView will display a list of cities, and the bottom TableView will display the census data.  Their content will be dynamically retrieved from the server. I would not know the number of cells returning from the server beforehand.  Both TableViews should auto-adjust their height based on the number of rows returned from the server.  The bottom tableview should follow immediately after the top tableview.   The tableviews should not have scrolling, instead the scrolling should be on the UIViewController level (so that it can look like a single continuous piece of content).

For example:

**Top TableView:**
-San Francisco
-Los Angeles
-Las Vegas
-Salt Lake City
...
**Bottom TableView:**
-Over 70: 3.3M
-Over 50: 2.3M
-Over 40: 1.1M
...

Any idea on how this should be done in Swift?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By changing bounds,tableview can be resize

```
 var rect1:CGRect = firstTable.frame //getting original bounds
    rect1.size.height = newht //change the new height here
    firstTable.frame = rect1

var rect2:CGRect = secondTable.frame
    rect2.origin.y = CGRectGetMaxY(rect2)
    secondTable.frame = rect2
```